Reset password, Supabase, Flutter. Cannot change passord after back in app
Short story:
After I reset the password for the user and the user is redirected back to my app. When I run await supabase.auth.updateUser(user) I get a Not logged in exception.
Long story:
I have a app created in Flutter, with supabase. I have some problems with my reset password function.
When click on reset password the user enters their email. I then execute
supabase.auth.resetPasswordForEmail(email, redirectTo: "parkeringsapp://parkering/glemtpassord");
The user gets the email and click on the reset password link.
The user is redirected to my app and I recive a deeplink code: parkeringsapp://parkering/glemtpassord?code=bb1de446-ddfc-43c3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Then I in my code check for the deeplink url, and if it contains glemtpassord I redirect the user to new password page.
After the user enters the new password I execute the codes
UserAttributes user = UserAttributes(password: password);
var response = await supabase.auth.updateUser(user);

But now the problems start. supabase.auth.updateuser throws a exception Not logged in. So the user haven't been logged in.
Question:
I thought that clicking the link would automaticly log the user in.
Any suggestions?
Haven't been able to find any similar problem

This is now solved. I used this code supabase.auth.getSessionFromUrl() and passed the URL. That fixed my problem.

I am having the same issue. Could you provide a more detailed step on how you used supabase.auth.getSessionFromUrl() to solve the problem?

Yes the supabase.auth.getSessionFromUrl() worked. Here is my code
As you see I use a function to handle my deeplink. There I extract the parameter from the url.
Future<void> handleLink(String link) async {
  final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;

  log().prnt("main", "handleLink   ${link}");
  if (link.isNotEmpty == true) {
    link = link.replaceAll(deepLinkUrl, "");
    link = link.replaceAll("parkeringsapp://parkering", "");
    log().prnt("main", "link tekst : ${link}");
    if (link.contains("#access_token=")) {
      String token = link.replaceAll("#access_token=", "");
      log().prnt("main", "Token :   ${token}");
      supabase.auth.signOut();
      //Navigator.pop(navigatorKey.currentContext!);
      //Navigator.pop(navigatorKey.currentContext!);
      navigatorKey.currentState?.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
      //Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GlemtPassord()));
      navigatorKey.currentState?.push(SafeAreaPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignInDrawer()));
    }
    else {
      var splittet = link.split("?");
      String command = splittet[0];
      String param = splittet[1];
      log().prnt("main", "Command  : ${command}   Param : ${param}");
      if (command == "glemtpassord") {
        String code = param.replaceAll("code=", "");
        log().prnt("main", "glemt passord  index : ${param.indexOf("code=")}   code :  ${code}");
        if (param.indexOf("code=") != -1) {
          log().prnt("main", "Inni redirect");
          //supabase.auth.exchangeCodeForSession(code);
          //blimedisameie("sameieid&sameiemellomromsameienavn");

          //await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
          //Navigator.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
          supabase.auth.getSessionFromUrl(Uri.parse(link) );
          navigatorKey.currentState?.push(SafeAreaPageRoute(builder: (context) => GlemtPassord()));

          spesiellRedirect = GlemtPassord();

        }
        if (param.indexOf("error=") != -1) {
          if (code.indexOf("is+invalid+or+has+expired") != -1) {

            //spesiellRedirect = SignInDrawer(dialogHeader: 'Feil under resetting', giDialogMelding: 'Kan ikke resette passord, prøv igjen.', );
            navigatorKey.currentState?.push(SafeAreaPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignInDrawer(dialogHeader: "Feil under resetting", giDialogMelding: "Kan ikke resette passord, prøv igjen.",)));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //setState(() {
  //_latestLink = link ?? 'Unknown';
  //});
}

So when I do the getsessionfromurl I get the session and is logged in. The GlemtPassord.dart contains code to get input from the user (new password) and then you call
                    UserAttributes user = UserAttributes(password: password);
                    var response = await supabase.auth.updateUser(user);

Hope this helps. I did google a ton of pages before I tried this.
